# How to use Shibboleth with an Application that uses Active Directory without mention of SAML support

Tags: active-directory, saml, shibboleth

In order to use Shibboleth as an identity provider or service provider for an application that uses AD, does that application have to support SAML or can it just support AD?

Can I use Shibboleth with an application that uses Active Directory for account management, including user credential validation with workgroups, local accounts, etc. even if the application does not mention any support of SAML, and what is the best method to do that?

Comment: What kind of application is it? An ASP.NET web application? In that case [Kentor.AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) to make your application use the Shibboleth Idp.

Comment: Please ask about one specific problem at a time - the Stack Overflow question-answer system works really bad with broad questions (that's why "too broad" is a close reason). Do you know what kind of technology the packaged app is built on? What web server is it run under (if it is a web app)?

Comment: ok. I deleted the broad comment. It is an IIS/.NET web app .exe install.